# JavaFX - Insert form textfield to SQLite Database

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx

I made a Form scene in my Application and wanted to insert the entered data to my SQLite Database when I hit the Save button. Here is the short code:

```
@FXML
private void handleSaveNewShop(ActionEvent event) {
    String name = shopname.getText();
    String adress = streetadress.getText();
    String city = cityname.getText();
    String state = statename.getText();
    String country = countryname.getText();
    String zip = zipcode.getText();
    String phonept1 = phonecountryid.getText();
    String phonept2 = phoneareaid.getText();
    String phonept3 = phoneothernumber.getText().toString();

    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    try{
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        System.out.print("\nConnecting to database...");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:FranchiseManagement.sqlite");
        System.out.println(" SUCCESS!\n");
        /*Tried this
        String insertToshopList = "INSERT INTO shopList (name, adress, city, state, country, zipcode, phonect, phonearea, phonemain)" + "values(name,adress,city,state,country,zip,phonept1,phonept2,phonept3)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(insertToshopList);
        */
        //And This
        //stmt.executeUpdate( "INSERT INTO shopList ('name','adress','city', 'state', 'country', 'zipcode', 'phonect', 'phonearea', 'phonemain') VALUES('"+name+"','"+adress+"','"+city+"'),'"+state+"','"+country+"','"+zip+"','"+phonept1+"','"+phonept2+"','"+phonept3+"'");
        conn.commit();
        System.out.println(" SUCCESS!\n");
        conn.close();
    } catch(SQLException se) {
    se.printStackTrace();
    }   
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I got NullPointException on my commited parts. The database connection seems okay and Connected.

Here is how my Database Looks:
[image: The Table]

[image: The Structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by removing the commit and added the INSERT into method well-formatted:

```
 @FXML
private void handleSaveNewShop(ActionEvent event) {
    String name = shopname.getText();
    String adress = streetadress.getText();
    String city = cityname.getText();
    String state = statename.getText();
    String country = countryname.getText();
    String zip = zipcode.getText();
    String phonept1 = phonecountryid.getText();
    String phonept2 = phoneareaid.getText();
    String phonept3 = phoneothernumber.getText();

    Connection conn;
    Statement stmt = null;

    try{
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        System.out.print("\nConnecting to database...");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:FranchiseManagement.sqlite");
        System.out.println(" SUCCESS!\n");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate( "INSERT INTO shopList ('name','adress','city', 'state', 'country', 'zipcode', 'phonect', 'phonearea', 'phonemain') VALUES('"+name+"','"+adress+"','"+city+"','"+state+"','"+country+"','"+zip+"','"+phonept1+"','"+phonept2+"','"+phonept3+"')");
        //conn.commit();
        System.out.println(" SUCCESS!\n");
        conn.close();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
        Logger.getLogger(DBConnect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }
```